# Опять (ChatGPT) двадцать пять?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, генеративный-ии

#### Описание

Вот [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/534913).
Вот череда ответов:

1. [2023-02-20 15:56:27](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498281/324730)
2. [2023-02-20 16:07:49](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498284/324730)
3. [2023-02-20 16:16:28](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498290/324730)
4. [2023-02-20 16:19:45](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498292/324730)
5. [2023-02-20 16:22:52](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498293/324730)
6. [2023-02-20 16:25:49](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498295/324730)
7. [2023-02-20 16:28:17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498296/324730)
8. [2023-02-20 16:36:45](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498301/324730)
9. [2023-02-20 16:42:05](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498304/324730)
10. [2023-02-20 16:46:43](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498307/324730)
11. [2023-02-20 16:49:36](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498310/324730)
12. [2023-02-20 16:54:35](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498314/324730)
13. [2023-02-20 17:12:19](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1498327/324730)

**13 ответов** за **1 час 15 минут 52 секунды**. Есть даже момент, где промежуток между ответов 3.5 минуты. Как человек который нередко отвечает на вопросы я бы хотел себе такую скорость...
Это еще отмечая комментарии, разговор, понимание вопросов, переключение между языков...
Кстати, немало языков знает этот участник - [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [swift](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), так же немало библиотек...

#### Вопрос

Почти на 99% уверен, что ответы сгенерированы.
Что думаете?

Comment: Таких людей в последнее время уже очень много на форуме, я лично наблюдал как минимум троих за прошедшую неделю, на каждого явно не стоит создавать отдельный топик, возможные пути решения уже были определены в прошлом вопросе.

Comment: @Павел я посмотрел этот вопрос прежде чем опубликовать. Там нету ответа. Что мне делать? Как мне отметить участника тревогой?

Comment: Там нет принятого ответа, потому что объективно правильного варианта действий - пока не определено, сообщество управляется участниками и следует поступать так, как большинство считает верным. 
У любого сообщения данного юзера нажимаете последовательно `Тревога` - `Требуется вмешательство модератора` и вводите причину - `ChatGPT`, после чего модераторы проверят и дадут бан на неделю.

Comment: @Павел понял, спасибо.

Comment: Все так. Кидайте тревогу "Требуется вмешательство". Можете оставить комментарий под ответом "похоже на GPT", так меньше шансов, что затеряется.

Comment: @Nofate судя по тому, что моя тревога на этого же участника уже сутки висит нерассмотренная — писать посты на мету или в чат эффективнее...

Comment: @andreymal вообще-то рассмотренная. Там неудачное комбо вышло: сразу два GPT-ответа. Один я удалил, второй пропустил.

Comment: А я слишком ленивый, чтобы открывать chatGPT и туда писать текст и получать ответ)) Сколько репки можно было бы заработать)) но лень...