# Как окончательно решить проблему с chatGPT?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ответы, нормы-поведения, генеративный-ии

**Проблема:**

На русском `StackOverFlow` появляется всё больше участников, которые используют `chatGPT` для публикации своих ответов. При чём такие участники **копируют** ответы из `gpt`, а не используют `gpt` как источник информации.

**Минусы текущего решения:**

Мне кажется, что нужно как-то автоматизировать бан таких пользователей. Я считаю, что недостаточно кидать на сообщения таких участников тревогу "требует вмешательство модератора", так как такую тревогу увидит только один модератор, и он может не придать ей должного значения. К тому же в поле описания тревоги нереально предоставить хоть какие-то доказательства, например список ответов, которые были даны с небольшим интервалом времени.

**Как я предлагаю решить проблему:**

Есть два по моему мнению неплохих варианта:

1. **Простой**: при обнаружении подозрительного участника создавать вопрос на мете с меткой gpt (она уже даже существует). Но тогда каждый вопрос будет про конкретного участника, и сообщество должно решить, что мы не будем закрывать такие вопросы как дубликаты (как закрыли [этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12394/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-chatgpt-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)).
2. **Сложный**: изобрести систему для вычисления этого дела. Она может работать, например, так: если сообщение получает специальную тревогу (неплохо бы было, если бы на сайте появилась тревога "chatGPT"), то сообщение отправляется в специальную очередь проверок. Если сообщение получает 5 голосов за то, что это `chatGPT`, то это сообщение отправляется на проверку модератору. Такой подход даёт следующее преимущество: к таким сообщениям (и к таким участникам) будет привлечено большее внимание, чем при прямой тревоге "требует вмешательство модератора".

Жизнь не стоит на месте, мир меняется, и наш сайт должен быть готов к неблагоприятным изменениям. Я рад буду услышать, нравятся ли вам мои методы решения проблемы , и будет так же неплохо, если вы приведёте свои методы =).

**P.S**

Мой вопрос **не дубликат** [моего недавнего вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12327/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-22-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-70-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-c), так как в том вопросе я привлекал внимание к конкретному участнику, а в этом вопросе я хочу поднять тему более глобальную.

Comment: Первый вариант - использование Меты не по делу,  Второй вариант по щелчку пальцев с нашей стороны никто делать будет. (Но разработчики озадачены этим вопросом, возможно однажды мы что-то увидим).

Comment: «5 голосов» — я не уверен, что будет набираться хотя бы два

Comment: @andreymal это лишь  для примера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая, что в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12327/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-22-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-70-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-c) ответы давались не только касательно определенного участника, но и более глобальные, я думаю этот вопрос все-таки можно считать дубликатом.

На каждого участника топик создавать точно не надо - это очень плохая идея. Мета превратится в обсуждение chatGPTшников, на текущем этапе пока их не настолько много, так что достаточно кидать тревогу модераторам и минусить ответы, других вариантов пока нет.

Общий алгоритм пока следующий:

У любого сообщения пользователя нажимаете последовательно:

`Тревога` - `Требуется вмешательство модератора` и вводите причину - `ChatGPT`.

Можете оставить комментарий под ответом "похоже на GPT", так меньше шансов, что затеряется.

Answer (score 2):

По первому предложению...

> ... обнаружении подозрительного участника создавать вопрос на мете...

В таком случае, как [уже писал Nofate в комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12399/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-chatgpt#comment53633_12399), Мета будет забита автоматически сгенерированными сообщениями. Помимо этого, как должен выглядеть алгоритм определения подозрительного участника и что считать подозрительным ответом?

По второму предложению...

> ... изобрести систему для вычисления этого...

Для этого нужно будет построить не один "велосипед", да и изобретать это никто не будет. Не стоит забывать про вычислительные мощности, которые не являются безграничными.

На мой взгляд, на данный момент проблему не решить. А если так, то нужно её возглавить. Какая в принципе разница откуда взялся ответ, если он качественный? ChatGPT, вселенная нашептала или грибочки? Другими словами, если ранее низкокачественные ответы могли писать уверенные в себе новички, то сейчас таких станет больше.
Выход только один: проверять ответы на корректность, но тут мы уже сталкиваемся с недостатком специалистом/знающих людей. Помимо этого при текущей процедуре регистрации/активации аккаунтов, бан любителей ИИ не поможет, так как им не составит большого труда создать новый аккаунт.

Comment: Мне самому импонирует идея насчет "возглавить". Но дьявол в деталях. Никто не хочет, чтобы экспертное сообщество SO превратилось в конвейер по валидации ответов от ИИ.
С другой стороны вот Quora пытается оседлать ChatGPT. Посмотрим, что из этого получится.

Comment: "бан любителей ИИ не поможет" - тем не менее банить то их надо.

Comment: "как должен выглядеть алгоритм определения подозрительного участника и что считать подозрительным ответом?" - если дано много ответов за короткое время, каждый ответ пишется минуты по три. Но видимо, вы правы, что проблему так просто не решить...

Comment: Разница есть, и гигантская. Во-первых, то что сгенерировано ChatGPT, нельзя публиковать без ссылки на источник, а все нарушающие делают именно это. Во-вторых, вы правда считаете, что хороший ответ может дать программа, которая просто комбинирует уже существующие в интернете тексты? Вы не думаете, что если это так, stackoverflow вообще не нужен?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight каким образом определить, что какой-либо текст сгенерирован ИИ? Его можно изменить, переименовать переменные и т.д. Да, на простые вопросы даёт хорошие результаты, но сам пользуюсь только как шпаргалкой, т.е. освежить память пойдёт, но в незнакомой для меня сфере пользоваться бы не стал. SO нужен и ещё как, но как бороться с теми кто использует это не владея предметом обсуждения/вопроса? Что Вы предлагаете? Ну вычислили мы злыдня, забанили. Через час он уже с другим аккаунтом заново шпарит. Я исхожу из текущих реалий. На SO нет хорошей репы и плохой - есть высокая и низкая :(

Comment: Одна из идей, лежащих на поверхности - это ограничивать количество ответов в единицу времени от новых участников. Для вопросов такие ограничения уже есть, настало время подумать о качестве ответов. Вторая - автоматические флаги по определенным закономерностям (которые модераторы используют уже сейчас). Что до проблемы новых аккаунтов, она и  без ChatGPT была. Спамеры тоже могут создавать новые аккаунты, но их же банят.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ограничение по времени: мы боремся с накруткой "репы" или с использованием ChatGPT?! Каким образом ограничение по времени исключит использование ИИ и повысит качество ответов?! Kакие закономерности должны быть у флагов, если, к примеру, я сейчас захочу пользоваться ChatGPT? А на счёт банов... Я считаю, что сейчас бан не действенная мера для аккаунтов с низкой "репой", т.к. терять им нечего, а создавать новый аккаунт можно хоть каждую минуту: почту создал, IP сменил, аккаунт создал. Отсюда и вытекают все проблемы со спамерами, с теми кто "болт" клал на бан и т.д.

Comment: Накрутка репы и ChatGPT - это вещи взаимосвязанные, в том то и дело. С учетом этого, другие ваши вопросы отпадают сами собой. Если невозможно будет накрутить много репы на одном аккаунте, то факт, что они могут наплодить их несколько, не очень уж важен.